Tkinter keybinding for shift cursor keys on Mac
The following keybindings are working fine on Windows, but don't execute the bound code on Mac. Are the keybindings different between Windows, Mac and Linux?
        self._kw.keyboard_win.bind("<Shift-KeyPress-Left>", self._on_shift_cursor_left)
        self._kw.keyboard_win.bind("<Shift-KeyPress-Right>", self._on_shift_cursor_right)
        self._kw.keyboard_win.bind("<Shift-KeyRelease-Left>", self._on_shift_cursor_left)
        self._kw.keyboard_win.bind("<Shift-KeyRelease-Right>", self._on_shift_cursor_right)

I tried a few alternatives, based on information I saw in similar questions.
For example:
"<Shift_L-KeyPress-Left>"
"<KeyPress-Shift_L-Left>"

These caused errors to be raised from tk.
I am able to bind to <KeyPress-Shift_L> or <KeyPress-Left>, but I want the combination of 'Shift and Left' and 'Shift and Right'.
ALL: I deleted the text of my keybinding strings and re-typed them, and now the bindings are working on all platforms (Mac, Win, and Linux). So, there must have been something (hidden) that the Mac version didn't like. Sorry for having not tried that before posing my question.

While there are differences on modifier keys, Shift were never be an issue. What have your tried to debug this ? For example have you looked into event.state and have you tried to bind Shift-Keypress

<Shift-KeyPress-Left> and <Shift-Left> both work on my mac.

In my _on_shift_cursor_left and _on_shift_cursor_right functions, I test the event.state to see if it was a press or release, and start or end some processing as a result. This works fine on Windows and Linux, but the event handler never gets called when run on my Mac. That is why I tried some alternative bindings (with no luck) and posted this question.

@BryanOakley - I deleted my strings and re-typed them, and now it is working on my Mac (as well as on Win and Linux).
